# What are the first/most influential works on galaxy-scale apocalypse?

Tags: history-of, apocalypse

It seems that planetary or galaxy-scale destruction is a common trope in science-fiction. I'm thinking of things like the halos in Halo or the Dakara weapon in Stargate, able to wipe out all lifeforms in the Galaxy in mere moments.
Are there any prior works showing similar technology? I'm mainly interested in litteratures but also welcome works in other media.
If so, what is the first notable work showing this concept, and what are the most influent ones?

Comment: The first work showing this concept seems like an on topic question. The first notable/influential one is leaning into opinion based territory; how do you define the terms? I suggest you just edit that part of the question out and just ask for the first.

Comment: I'm actually interesting in both knowing the first ones and the 'most ancient influential/popular ones' if that makes any sense (the ones that made this trope well-known).
I've got trouble coming up with a better wording for my question regarding the latter part. If someone could edit the question about this, it would be welcome, else I'll do it to only focus on the 'first one' aspect.

Comment: If galactic omnicide counts, there's the Thrintun Suicide Night from Niven's *World of Ptavvs* (1966).